# Report Showing Diff between 2 Commits

Tags: git, tfs, git-diff, tfs-reports

We are using git for TFS. I'm looking for something that can do essentially a git-diff on all commits between two dates and times. We know we can build something manually, but for compliance reasons, it's easier to get something through if it already exists.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow, sorry.

Comment: I've updated the question as I'm not looking for just software recommendations. I use git with TFS and am looking to see how others have been able to produce diff reports to provide to compliance officers.

Answer (score 1):

To show the diffs for a single commit, do

```
git show $thatcommit
```

To show the diffs from one commit to any other commit, do

```
git diff $theonecommit $theothercommit
```

To show the individual diffs for each of a set of commits, do e.g.

```
git log -c -p master..topic    # to get all the unmerged topic commits
```

Comment: I'm currently using git diff $theonecommit $theothercommit, but the formatting isn't the best to just copy and paste. Looking for either (a) report in TFS (b) some example that shows this in a nice format (html, pdf, etc) without the need to copy and paste.

Comment: I confess I can't think of any reason to want a diff in pdf format.  Could you update your question to explain what use you have in mind here?